# AKMicrophone in AudioKit appears to have no default init(), fails to initialize

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, akmicrophone

This code is in a class that contains my AudioKit code. The call 'mic = AKMicrophone' fails.

```
private let mic     : AKMicrophone
let tracker         : AKFrequencyTracker
private let silence : AKBooster

init() {
    do {
        try AKManager.start()
        akStartSucceeded = true
    } catch {
        akStartSucceeded = false
    }
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
}
```

The error message is

2020-10-08 16:51:15.256166-0700 Tuner[55400:16846610] Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'AudioKit.AKMicrophone'

When I look at the definition of AKMicrophone, I see '@objc override dynamic public init()'

I have gotten similar messages and fixed the problem by finding an init(...) in the definition code that worked. I see nothing here. Is this an AudioKit bug?

Using AKMicrophoneTracker works, but I found references indicating that is going away soon and that AKFrequencyTracker is recommended.

XCode 12.0.1
iOS 14
AK is incorporated via CocoaPods and code was updated about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you update to AudioKit v5 using Swift Package Manager. SPM is a lot more convenient than Cocoapods. And, for what you're doing AudioKit v5 has what you need and is more stable. Its not officially released, but you can still use it and we're getting very close.

Comment: OK, I am well along in moving to AK 5, but I cannot figure out how to use PitchTap. What are the arguments to the handler? How often is it called? Should I be ignoring this handler and periodically accessing the frequency property? I just need some kind of example to follow and I can't find anything.

Comment: Check out the AudioKit Cookbook project, there's a tuner in there: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/

Comment: Thanks. I had not stumbled across the v5 Cookbook. Perhaps it should be referenced somewhere that will make it easier to find.

Comment: We are transitioning to v5, which is now the default branch, even though its not yet officially released. The cookbook is in numerous places and will be on our websites as well, shortly.